# Neo4j OGM Connect to existing Embeded DB

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

good day. i have some theoretical question.
i made application that uses neo4j to traverse graphs and make some external calculations on each node. traverse process initiated by external event.
during traverse process nodes properties may change according calculation results.
this made by

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File (this.DB_PATH));
GraphDatabaseService.traversalDescription();
```

now i'd like to use neo4j OGM to use domain classes in path extenders code  instead self-made node-wrappers. also i`d like to use domain classes to populate DB with nodes and relations , and change properties of nodes from external source (REST for example).
But i can't find way to get Session or SessionFactory to existing and operational database. 
is it possible to  connect to database , created as embedded and conducting some calculations in one module , from another module by BOLT protocol, execute some queries, use OGM features?

Answer (score 0):

The OGM cannot be used from path expanders / traversals (at least not easily).

To use OGM with embedded database you have 2 options

- use the standard configuration as described in the [reference documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:configuration:driver:embedded)
- set use `Components.setDriver` to set the driver manually, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977296/951609) for details